# While finding out chiral centers should lone pair be considered as a group?

Tags: organic-chemistry, stereochemistry

[image]

My book says it is a chiral center.

Should I count lone pairs as one of the groups while finding chiral center ?

Comment: Btw, entering even a vague query like "sulfur chiral" on Google gives you the answer... I'm not trying to discourage you from asking questions but honestly you should first and foremost be able to try and help yourself.

Comment: I am asking in general. Do we consider lone paira while finding chirality centre

Comment: No for nitrogen, yes for sulfur and phosphorus. Maybe try googling "lone pair chiral", the first hit tells you the answer.

Comment: Chiral compound does not depends on chirality center. There are compounds with no chiral center but are chiral .

Comment: What are you telling me that for? In the compound you used, if the central atom is a chiral centre, then the compound is chiral. If you want to argue about the existence of other forms of chirality then you should not have attached an image of a simple sulfoxide like that.

Comment: I found this example in book so i gave it .I know it is chiral I mentioned what my books says .

Comment: The question you stated as duplicate is about trigonal S not tetrahedral.

Comment: I meam reffered mine as duplicate

Comment: @Pi5: firstly, sulphoxide is not tetrahedral. It's trigonal pyramidal. Secondly, Yes. The lone pair is analogous to a 4th group. But sometimes inversions will take place making it impossible to resolve the compound. In case of sulphur, it's not easy for inversion to take place, but for nitrogen, the inversions are rapid.

Comment: @orthocresol shouldnt you consider the lone pair as a 4th group of inversions are restricted?